ArrayBuffer does not take this parameter
I am working in Scala with Eclipse.
Can someone explain why I am getting this error?

ArrayBuffer does not take this parameter in line
 var ArrayBuffer1 = ArrayBuffer(1,2,3,4,5)

The following is the code that causes this error.
import scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer;

object ArrayBuffer {
  def main(args: Array[String]){
    
    var ArrayBuffer1 = ArrayBuffer(1,2,3,4,5)
    ArrayBuffer1.foreach(println)
    
  }
}


Which Scala version? This should be working just fine. I suspect you use old versions as ScalaEclipse is obsolete for several years now. Try out IntelliJ or VsCode or scala-cli.

You called your object ArrayBuffer, which hides the import. The compiler then tries to apply arguments to the object, which it can't.
Renaming it to something different will make it work as expected (in the following example, ArrayBufferMain):
import scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer;

object ArrayBufferMain {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    
    var ArrayBuffer1 = ArrayBuffer(1,2,3,4,5)
    ArrayBuffer1.foreach(println)
    
  }
}

The Scala compiler 2.13.14 reports what I mentioned as a warning. You might want to check that as well.
A couple of notes:

in your code, you use procedure syntax, which is deprecated (see here)
Just FYI, if you have name clashes another possibility either qualifying the package or aliasing your imports, as in the following example

import scala.collection.mutable.{ArrayBuffer => AB};

object ArrayBuffer {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    
    var ArrayBuffer1 = AB(1,2,3,4,5)
    ArrayBuffer1.foreach(println)
    
  }
}

